# Create an install exe file with binaries and redistributables for XNA - VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0, binaries

I'm actually working on a game during my internship. I made it with XNA game studio and used Visual studio 2012 (used a topic on this site to install it...). Now that i'm almost done with the code, I'm looking into make an exe file which will install the game. As it may be installed on computers where XNA and .NET redistributables aren't installed, the package should install them with the game, or it'll not work.

So I'm looking for two things :

- How to generate binary files for my XNA project, as I don't want all the users to read my work. I know how to do it on VS2010, but on VS2012 I just can't find where's the option to generate them.
- Once I got the binaries, I want to know how to make an exe file which will install them and the redistributables. I know there's some tools to do it, but I don't know what to use.

Thanks in advance for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

They have removed the installer project type from VS2012, checkout WIX. Its a bit clumsy to get started, but once you get a hang of it, its much more powerfull than VS2010 installer project

http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: I just installed WiX. Wow, seems like it's hard to use when you don't know how it works. But i'll try with it, it seems really complete. If you got well explained tutorials to learn how to deal with it, it would be nice to share it with me :) Thanks for helping !

Comment: Sorry I didn't find a solid tutorial when I did this, I had to google and work together the pieces. You can look here for how I did it in my open source project https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/tree/master/BuildTools

Comment: I actually found something : I can include the redistributable files in the one click application file generated by visual studio 2012, by going in the properties file, in the publishing section, and clicking on prerequisites. So I can put Windows Installer and the .NET Framework 4.5, but I need XNA redist too, which isn't on the list.. I just need to figure why it isn't, and i'll be able to deploy the application.